# Классовый тип для работы со структурами типа "Вектор"

Tags: java, vector

[![На фото я уже использую готов Vector
а мне нужно сделать собственный.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJbZd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJbZd.png)1. Создать параметризованный класс для работы со структурой типа Vector -
одномерный динамический массив с переменным количеством элементов. Тип элемента
массива предоставляется параметром шаблона.
2. Предусмотреть конструктор для создания вектора и инициализации его
обычным одномерным массивом соответствующего типа.
3. Реализовать компонентные методы:
- get - доступа к элементу по индексу;
- concat - конкатенации двух векторов;
- equals - сравнение двух векторов.
- size - количество элементов вектора;
- front - ссылка на первый элемент;
- back - ссылка на последний элемент;
- swap - обмен значениями с другим вектором;
- insert - вставить элемент в предоставленную позицию;
- push_back - добавить новый элемент в конец вектора;
- pop_back - изъять последний элемент;
- erase - удалить элемент в предоставленной позиции;
- find - найти элемент в векторе и вернуть его позицию;
- accumulate - накопление суммы или произведения;
- for_each - обработка элементов по предоставленной процедуре;
- max, min - поиск максимального и минимального элементов;
- sort - упорядочение элементов в порядке возрастания или
уменьшения.

Comment: нужна помощь.
буду очень признателен.

Comment: Сами пробовали? Что то не получилось?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я просто не понимаю ничего. А нужно сдать эту работу а то есть возможность что меня выгонят из универа (

Comment: Нужно начать понимать, иначе смысл учиться в универе?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ согласен с вами. а что делать если к сдаче 2 недели а я не рыба не мясо

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я Хочу изучить но так скажем deadline поджимает а я так верстал понемногу а ООП НЕ идет

Comment: почитать книгу для начинающих, про классы, ооп, java, создать класс, добавить к нему первый метод, потом второй, в целом это не сложно... и если Вы сделаете это не сами, преподаватель все равно это поймет, задав пару вопросов..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ то есть мне не помогут?

Comment: помочь разобраться - вснгда пожалуйста, спрашивайте что Вам не понятно, по частям

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хорошо.
можете помочь составить алгоритм
для этой работы.
то есть последовательность использования того или иного метода

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я смотрел как он реализован не использовал интегрированный JDK вектор. Там очень много и ничего не понятно

Comment: а какие классы из стандартной библиотеки Вам нельзя использовать?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мне нужно создать с 0 сам вектор.
после чего использовать его и выполнить все перечисленные ниже действия size, get, capacity, lastElement, indexOf, insertElementAt. то есть мне готов вектор узаты нельзя

Comment: добавил изображение

Comment: ArrayList можно? :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну по идее это одно и тоже.
поэтому я уже смотрю как реализовать свой ArrayList) так что я посмотрю если все ок тогда я сам сделаю если нет то хз что делать

Comment: Ну в целом Вы на верном пути, реализуйте свой список, добавьте к нему необходимые методы